# How to filter out rows that have duplicates in a database request

Tags: php, mysql

I have duplicate data in my table `colors`:

---

red, red, blue, black, yellow, orange, orange

---

I tried to use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT color FROM colors;
```

but the result I got is `red, blue, black, yellow, orange` and I just want it to return `blue, black, yellow`. How can I do that?

Comment: DISTINCT only lists the different values in this column.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use [`HAVING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

```
SELECT color
FROM colors
GROUP BY color
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This selects the "color" column from the table "colors", groups the values by equality (i.e. into buckets whose "color" value is the same), then filters based on groups who have a count of 1 (i.e. they are unique).